# Oracle VM virtualbox cropping

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, virtualbox

I am trying to setup Ubuntu 14.04 with Virtualbox and the setup goes fine, except is is very slow and laggy, as a side issue how can I speed up the virtual computer.

My main issue is that during setup the screen gets cropped and important things like the continue button are not shown in the window. Sometimes I can use "tab" to select it but normally that does not work and I have tried a few times but I still can't get past the setup menus.

Anyone know how to fix the cropping issue and will it persist after set up?

Comment: Please add `virtualbox guest additions` and for speed "alter" your vm settings from the Virtualbox Settings!

Comment: Yep, that worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With newer releases of Ubuntu you will be able to adjust the virtual screen geometry by dragging the window with the mouse on installing. Older releases such as 14.04. stay in a low resolution screen until the virtual graphics adapter was installed with the [guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm).

To still be able to see off-screen parts of dialogs press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> while pressing the left mouse button to move the dialog around.

Comment: Thanks for your reply that worked for me. I don't know what the issue was but a simple turn on and off again seemed to fix everything.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your VirtualBox-Window have any scroll bars? Otherwise, test the different display settings in virtual box (fullscreen, ...) - one might work.

Once you have your OS set up, you can add the virtualbox guest additions. If everything works as intended, you should be able to resize your virtualbox window and your guest os will adapt its display / screen resolution to it. My experience is that this usually works on major window managers/desktops, albeit with some small glitches.